# QGIS Console error Libgrass

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins

Just installed  QGIS 1.8. on Mac OSX

- Installed GSL
- Install GDAL 1.9 Complete
- Installed QGIS

keep getting this console error message in QGIS.

```
Failed to load /Applications/QGIS.app/Contents/MacOS/../PlugIns/qgis/libgrassrasterprovider.so (Reason: Cannot load library /Applications/QGIS.app/Contents/MacOS/../PlugIns/qgis/libgrassrasterprovider.so: (dlopen(/Applications/QGIS.app/Contents/MacOS/../PlugIns/qgis/libgrassrasterprovider.so, 5): Library not loaded: /Applications/GRASS-6.4.app/Contents/MacOS/lib/libgrass_gis.6.4.2.dylib
  Referenced from: /Applications/QGIS.app/Contents/PlugIns/qgis/libgrassrasterprovider.so
  Reason: image not found))
```

and

```
Couldn't import Python module 'psycopg2' for communication with PostgreSQL database. Without it you won't be able to run PostGIS manager.
```

when i try and use the postGIS admin tool

Anyone know how i can fix this..

Comment: Did you install GRASS? If not and you don't need it, ignore the warning.

Answer (score 3):

For PostgreSQL to work (2nd error message) you need to install psycopg2 module from http://www.kyngchaos.com/software/python